# One button go back and forth between 2 pages

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-button

I have one button that I'd like to go back and forth between two pages in a `ViewPager`. I know how to make a button go to the specific page. I just want the same button to go back to the previous page `OnClick.` And for them to cycle between just those 2 pages out of 3.

Here's what I already have.

I'm sure this is very simple to do, but
since I'm still a java noob, any code examples would be fantastic!

```
settingsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  [ViewPager.getCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29) to get Current item from ViewPager then move it next or Previous as :

```
settingsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // get Current Item from ViewPager
            int currentpage=mPager.getCurrentItem();
            switch(currentpage){

             case 0:
             mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
             break;
             case 1:
             mPager.setCurrentItem(0, true); 
             break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be as simple as that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple switch-case to check which page you're on and change to the required page:

```
switch(mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
case 0:
    //First page. Change to whatever page you want
    break;
case 1:
    //Second page. Change to whatever page you want
    break;
default:
    //Neither of the first two pages. Do whatever you want
    break;
}
```